# Split a cell that contains a phrase, placing each character of the phrase in a cell

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, split, char

I'm working with a 16 column x 4 row LCD display and to keep track of my project screens I'm saving it to a google sheets spreadsheet.

I would like to type a sentence and it already puts each character in a cell, maybe using some kind of script, because I've already tested the **Data > Split text to columns** tool and I can only split a sentence using the space separator, comma, etc. .

Example image of what I want to do on google sheets

[image: Example image of what I want to do on google sheets]

Comment: for a CENTER alignment how do you intend to inject words with odd number of characters? to the left or to the right by one space? also for the TEST SIZE... why did you jump one space to the right? does the test size contain empty space before test?

Comment: and what if the sentence is longer than 16 squares?

Comment: @player0 Just to exemplify random cases. In case of an odd number, I usually leave the smallest space on the left side. We calculate the word size before placing, we look for the correct abbreviation in case the phrase does not fit

Comment: The objective is to speed up writing in the worksheet, for each character of a sentence I need to press the arrow to the side, if it is done manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to just split stuff by characters you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")))
```

[image]

to cut off longer stuff you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")), 9^9, 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Wowwww nice dude. Works like a charm!!!